# Dual boot W7 64bit + Ubuntu, W7 does not boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, partitioning, multi-boot

Dual boot W7 64bit + Ubuntu installed.  Ubuntu appears to work fine, but W7 will not boot. I downloaded boot repair and did the recommended repair. That did not work.

I now have 6 partitions:

- /dev/sda1/, "PQSERVICE", 14 GB
- /dev/sda2/, 105 MB, NTFS, "bootable", not mounted when Ubuntu running
- /dev/sda3/, 253 GB, Ext4, not mounted when Ubuntu running
- /dev/sda4/, 373 GB, "Extended", "container for logical partitions", no filesystem shown
- /dev/sda5/, 369 GB, Ext4, mounted at / when Ubuntu running
- /dev/sda6/, 3.9 GB, Ext 4, "Linux swap"

Looks to my inexperienced eye like the installer incorrectly labeled sda3 as ext4 while it was and should still be NTFS.  Maybe when the boot loader tries to boot in sda2, it needs to see something in sda3, and can't read it. In any case, how do I get W7 running without disturbing my Ubuntu installation?